# How to get local files on Chromium Embedded Framework on Mac

Tags: macos, chromium-embedded

I am using CEF (https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) to embed a html5 inside Chromium browser.

If i embed my web app in Windows i can browse files using file:///path

If i use Mac i don't know how to call local files; i've tried to copy files inside .app file in Contents/MacOS or COntents/Resources folders but cannot access that using file:///   protocol.

How can i get local files path on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an objective-c context you could use:

```
    CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line = CefCommandLine::GetGlobalCommandLine();

    if ( command_line->HasSwitch("url") ) {
        path = command_line->GetSwitchValue("url");
    }

    if ( path.empty() ) {
        path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        path = "file://" + path + "/html/something/index.html";
    }
```